# Accessing elements of a vector in a map of vectors

Tags: c++

I want to create a map of vectors. I want the vector to be a private member variable however so when I need to increase the size of the vector for a particular key in the map it does it for all other keys in the map also(would that work?). This will be a map of vectors(of ints) where the keys are strings. My question is how to access a particular element in the vector to change is value in C++. Something along the lines of map_name['word'].[3] = 2 if i wanted to set the third value of the vector of "word" to 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivfoe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN74g.png)
Im still having trouble figuring out how to make it so the size of each vector for all the keys in the maps is modifiable so i can increase the size of each vector at any point along the program. This is b/c the vector size is unknown at runtime and iterating through each element in the map to change the vector size will take too long.

Comment: Please post code, rather than a description of code.  The latter is much harder to read, and more error-prone.

Comment: Could you maybe post a code example of what you would like to do?

Comment: What is the dot between both pair of []?

Comment: "_I want the vector to be a private member variable however so when I need to increase the size of the vector for a particular key in the map it does it for all other keys in the map also(would that work?)._" - Yes, you can make your imaginary class do that. It sounds like you may have chosen the wrong approach for whatever it is that you're doing but, you can do it.

Comment: _"iterating through each element in the map to change the vector size will take too long."_ Really? How big's the map?

Comment: the map is for words in a corpus where you are measuring repeat occurrences of words in addition to occurrences of words with certain labels (subject of corpus entry)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is recursive.

That is, when you do:

```
expression[key] = value;
```

your `expression` doesn't have to just be a variable name; it can be a more complex expression, such as `map_name["word"]`.

So:

```
map_name["word"][3] = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, yes it is possible as mentioned in one of the comments, you can make your imaginary class to do that.
And in the second question, you'll have to access an element of a vector which is an element of a map like this:
`map1["abc"][1] = 2`
The '.' you added was unnecessary because you're accessing an element inside another element, just like a 2D array